# A discontinuous function such that $f(y) - f(x) \leq (x-y)^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I came across the following task

> Suppose $f(x)$ to be defined on $[0, 1]$ and $f(0) = 0$ also $\forall \ x, y: 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 \rightarrow f(y) - f(x) \leq (y-x)^2$. Then there is a function $f(x)$ that is discontinuous on $[0, 1]$

I can't imagine this situation because I thought that if for all, arbitrarily closely located to each other, points, the values ​​of the function differ even less it means a uniform continuity which entails a continuity. But it seems I was wrong. Could you please help me to think up a such function? Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: $f$ could be decreasing.

Comment: Take $f$ to be minus Dirichlet function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh, exactly. Thank you a lot!